# How to run a SQL script in the SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I previously run a SQL script on APEX with the SQL Workshop but my account was blocked. So, I tried to run this in SQL Developer but I don't know how, I already have a connection between Oracle Application Express and SQL Developer.

Comment: you can run the script, what you're asking is why won't it create my sequence? because a sequence by that name already exists. you can rename it, or you can drop it first, then the CREATE will work

Comment: In fact, don't create something, even the tables. I already modify the question.

Comment: i don't understand your question to be honest. what are you trying, that's not working? The SQL Worksheet in SQL Developer let's you run your DDL like you have shown in your code sample

Comment: Thank for you time!, I already fixed my problem (your answer help me a lot and I already modify the question for future inquiries). Sorry for any inconvenience but I didn't know how explain in a correct way my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect in SQL Developer.

Open a SQL Worksheet - we usually open one for you upon successful connection.

Put your code in.

Hit F5 or use the Execute as Script button.

[image]

We'll rip through your statements.

[image]

I talk about this more [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/06/running-multiple-queries-in-oracle-sql-developer/).